# How to create rdd of large data available as python collection instead of file

Tags: python, apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark

I am new to spark and trying to ingest data from a webservice to orc hive table using Pyspark. The webservice response (Json) is a batch of records with the url of the next batch.I am converting each of the response to a collection and parallelizing using below command.

```
Rdd=sc.parallelize(response1)
```

Next I am merging all the subsequent responses into the 
existing Rdd using union.

```
Rdd=Rdd.union(sc.parallelize(response2))
Rdd=Rdd.union(sc.parallelize(response3))
...
Rdd=Rdd.union(sc.parallelize(responseN))
```

However the above approach gives me Spark java.lang.OutOfMemoryError on merging 15th or 16th response.

Earlier my understanding was whenever we parallelize() a collection, spark distributes it across nodes. And multiple nodes collectively be able to hold such large dataset. But looks like it is keeping all the responses on Drivers main memory because of data locality. Is my understanding correct?

2 - Is there anyway I can get information on where exactly  partitions are located on cluster?

3 - Is there anyway I can force spark to redistribute partition across nodes?

4 - Later on I tried to set storage level of Rdd to DISK_ONLY in hope that data will be maintained on disk instead of RAM. But I got the exact same error again so I am even more confused on what does this of option do then?

5 - What would be a better way of solving this problem. I thought of doing all the transformation on fly without the need of dumping whole dataset on disk, the moving on hdfs and finally reading it again for processing?

Comment: You could try increasing the executor memory

Comment: @cricket_007 will try and confirm. But shouldn't spark automatically manage this, like move few partitions to disk or other nodes if it ran out of space in ram. I mean we may not have control on how much data will be returned so even if it worked for some executor memory-volume combination it may fail again if data volume exceeds certain limit?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. `spark.executor.memory` defaults to `1g`, and all retries will use a maximum of that same amount. Plus, there is some overhead between Python and the JVM

Answer (score 0):

> Earlier my understanding was whenever we parallelize() a collection, spark distributes it across nodes.

That's only partially true. `ParallelCollectionRDD` keeps a reference to the original data, so it requires at least as much memory on the driver, and therefore is not scalable.

Instead of using `parallelize`, you should use some higher order function, to fetch data:

```
urls = sc.parallelize([url1, url2, url3, ..., urlN])

urls.map(make_request)
```

Comment: One limitation with data source I am using is that nth url can only be fetched once I have pulled data by hitting n-1th url. So I will not have all the urls before, they can only be fetched serially one after another.

Comment: wouldn't any action performed on this rdd will again run on driver since original url list is local to driver?Or will it be distributed before performing action?